# Using a method name as the value for an instance variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to round out my Javascript knowledge. This seems like such a simple thing, yet it's puzzling me.

I have a need to store a method name as a variable. Reducing my test case to the smallest possible size, results in the following:

```
var someobj = { 
  someMethod: function() {
      console.log('woo');
  }, 
  somevariable: this.someMethod
}
```

There are no callbacks, everything's nice and simple.

```
console.log(someobj.someMethod);
```

Returns:

```
[Function]
```

Great. But:

```
console.log(someobj.somevariable)
```

Returns:

```
undefined
```

I was expecting it to return '[Function]'. Why is this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring objects in JSON - format, there is no `this` keyword. (well, there is, but i refers to the `this` of the outer context, for example `window` in a global context) You cannot access the current object in such a declaration.
You will thus need to set that variable afterwards, something like this:

```
var someobj = { 
  someMethod: function() {
      console.log('woo');
  } 
}
someobj.somevariable = someobj.someMethod;
```